# How to make a payment with square from Dart code in flutter?

Tags: api, http, dart, payment, square

I need make payments with square, I used square_in_app_payments plugin but it only give me a nonce string that seems I have to send it to checkout api with items information inside JSON in http request, but I don't understand how to make it.

I only tried from postman make some samples fo square.

```
POST /v2/locations/{{location_id}}/checkouts HTTP/1.1
Host: connect.squareup.com
Authorization: Bearer {{access_token}}
Content-Type: application/json
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 5d2c05ae-11d6-42bd-bd1e-47fa44621a98

{
  "idempotency_key": "60f919ba-2042-4402-bc66-e6455ec32349",
  "order": {
    "reference_id": "reference_id",
    "line_items": [
      {
        "name": "Printed T Shirt",
        "quantity": "2",
        "base_price_money": {
          "amount": 1500,
          "currency": "USD"
        },
        "discounts": [
          {
            "name": "7% off previous season item",
            "percentage": "7"
          },
          {
            "name": "$3 off Customer Discount",
            "amount_money": {
              "amount": 300,
              "currency": "USD"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Slim Jeans",
        "quantity": "1",
        "base_price_money": {
          "amount": 2500,
          "currency": "USD"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Woven Sweater",
        "quantity": "3",
        "base_price_money": {
          "amount": 3500,
          "currency": "USD"
        },
        "discounts": [
          {
            "name": "$11 off Customer Discount",
            "amount_money": {
              "amount": 1100,
              "currency": "USD"
            }
          }
        ],
        "taxes": [
          {
            "name": "Fair Trade Tax",
            "percentage": "5"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "discounts": [
      {
        "name": "Father's day 12% OFF",
        "percentage": "12"
      },
      {
        "name": "Global Sales $55 OFF",
        "amount_money": {
          "amount": 5500,
          "currency": "USD"
        }
      }
    ],
    "taxes": [
      {
        "name": "Sales Tax",
        "percentage": "8.5"
      }
    ]
  },
  "ask_for_shipping_address": true,
  "merchant_support_email": "merchant+support@website.com",
  "pre_populate_buyer_email": "example@email.com",
  "pre_populate_shipping_address": {
    "address_line_1": "1455 Market St.",
    "address_line_2": "Suite 600",
    "locality": "San Francisco",
    "administrative_district_level_1": "CA",
    "postal_code": "94103",
    "country": "US",
    "first_name": "Jane",
    "last_name": "Doe"
  }
}
```

I need to know how to take the nonce string from card form of square_in_app_payments plugin and send it in http request for complete the payment.

Comment: A few things: 1) with a nonce you will want to call `Charge` (not `Checkout`) listed here: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-transactions-charge. Also, we have a full README on how to do this included in the flutter plugin, please let me know if this doesn't help: https://github.com/square/in-app-payments-flutter-plugin/blob/master/example/take_a_payment.md

Comment: Thanks for the response, it was very helpful, but I have the problem that the example and the documentation says I need a Square Mobile Backend of my own with a service to make the payment. Is not there a server that has square ready to use it?

Comment: No, in order to charge a nonce you'll need your own backend service. If you don't want to use your own backend service, then I recommend using Checkout API which will redirect a user to a Square-hosted payment form.